# Ansible role of duplicate works for the absolute parameters only

Tags: ansible

I have playbook like this

```
test_playbook/
├── dep_test.yaml
├── my_hosts_file
└── roles
    ├── common
    │   └── vars
    │       └── main.yaml
    ├── dep_test
    │   ├── meta
    │   │   └── main.yaml
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yaml
    ├── dep_test_a
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yaml
    └── dep_test_b
        ├── meta
        │   └── main.yaml
        └── tasks
            └── main.yaml
```

Files content are as below.

**dep_test.yaml**

```
- hosts: my_host
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
      - common
      - dep_test
```

**my_hosts_file**

```
[my_host]
localhost
```

**roles/common/vars/main.yaml**

```
python_version: "3"
```

**roles/dep_test/tasks/main.yaml**

```
- name: debug test
  debug:
      msg: test debug
```

**roles/dep_test/meta/main.yaml**

```
dependencies:
    - role: dep_test_a
#     pyenv_versions: ["{{ python_version }}"]
      pyenv_versions: ["3"]
    - role: dep_test_b
#     python_versions: ["{{ python_version }}"]
      python_versions: ["3"]
```

**roles/dep_test_a/tasks/main.yaml**

```
- name: Dep test a
  debug:
      msg: "Dependency test a called with {{ pyenv_versions }}"
```

**roles/dep_test_b/tasks/main.yaml**

```
- name: Dep test b
  debug:
      msg: "Dependency test b called with {{ python_versions }}"
```

**roles/dep_test_b/meta/main.yaml**

```
dependencies:
    - role: dep_test_a
#     pyenv_versions: "{{ python_versions }}"
      pyenv_versions: ["3"]
```

When I pass parameter as `["3"]` it works fine and apply the [Role Duplication and Execution](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-duplication-and-execution)

```
ansible-playbook dep_test.yaml -i my_hosts_file -u root --ask-pass
SSH password:

PLAY [my_host] ****************************************************************************************************

TASK [dep_test_a : Dep test a] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Dependency test a called with [u'3']"
}

TASK [dep_test_b : Dep test b] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Dependency test b called with [u'3']"
}

TASK [dep_test : debug test] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test debug"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

When I change the parameter from `["3"]` to use the variable form `common/vars/main.yaml`'s `python_version`, it fail the `Duplication rule` and execute same role with duplicate arguments.

After change code would be

**roles/dep_test/meta/main.yaml**

```
dependencies:
    - role: dep_test_a
      pyenv_versions: ["{{ python_version }}"]
#     pyenv_versions: ["3"]
    - role: dep_test_b
      python_versions: ["{{ python_version }}"]
#     python_versions: ["3"]
```

**roles/dep_test_b/meta/main.yaml**

```
dependencies:
    - role: dep_test_a
      pyenv_versions: "{{ python_versions }}"
#     pyenv_versions: ["3"]
```

Playbook execution output.

```
ansible-playbook dep_test.yaml -i my_hosts_file -u root --ask-pass
SSH password:

PLAY [my_host] ****************************************************************************************************

TASK [dep_test_a : Dep test a] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Dependency test a called with [u'3']"
}

TASK [dep_test_a : Dep test a] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Dependency test a called with [u'3']"
}

TASK [dep_test_b : Dep test b] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Dependency test b called with [u'3']"
}

TASK [dep_test : debug test] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test debug"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Role `dep_test_a` called 2 times with same arguments `[u'3']`

```
TASK [dep_test_a : Dep test a] ***********************************************************************************

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Dependency test a called with [u'3']"
}

TASK [dep_test_a : Dep test a] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Dependency test a called with [u'3']"
}
```

One for the dependencies in `dep_test` role and another for `dep_test_b`.

As per the rule of dependencies, this should be called only once.

Question: Why dependent role runs twice when passing the parameter?

Comment: @techraf, if you check the behavior, the role a is running twice when a variable is set, but not when the value is hardcoded. I can only think about the variables not being matched until calling the role, so the role doesn't match the value beforehand and that's why it's re-running the role.

Comment: @techraf sorry for the confusion, I updated my post with Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: Why dependent role runs twice when passing the parameter?

Answer: Because Ansible uses lazy evaluation, hence Jinja2 templating is not being triggered until the variable is used.

Passing a variable to a role is not considered a usage, so it passes and compares the templates, not the values.

You call the `dep_test_a` role twice:

```
- role: dep_test_a
  pyenv_versions: ["{{ python_version }}"]
```

and:

```
- role: dep_test_a
  pyenv_versions: "{{ python_versions }}"
```

`["{{ python_version }}"]` is not equal to `"{{ python_versions }}"`, thus Ansible executes the role twice.

---

And btw, the code to illustrate the behaviour in the question can be shortened to:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    my_var1: 1
    my_var2: 1
  roles:
    - role: my_role
      role_param: "{{ my_var1 }}"
    - role: my_role
      role_param: "{{ my_var2 }}"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, if we mentioned dependencies and add that role in main playbook (as you did), is there any difference?

Comment: No, there will be no difference.